# Rendering hill shade after texturing it

Tags: qgis, 3d, rendering, blendergis

Does anyone know if it's possible to:

- make a hillshade,
- render it with blender
- go to Photoshop and place a layer on
  top of it [like a tint, color bands,
  or terrain data]

and then render it once more, in Blender?

something like this:

[image: here's what I'm trying to do]

Comment: In Blender > https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS  (Workflow > https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/domlysz/blenderGIS/flowchart.jpg)